# É possivel fazer um sistema de upload de arquivos sem utitlizar php, apenas com jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Já pesquisei em vários sites mas nunca consegui saber se era mesmo possivel, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A resposta é sim e não.

Sim, é possível fazer um [sistema de upload sem PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19202404/1606920).

E não, não é possível fazer apenas com [jQuery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info).

O que acontece é que jQuery é um framework de [JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) que funciona no client-side (front-end). No entanto, não tem efeito nenhum você fazer o upload do front-end, se não tiver nada no back-end (server-side) para receber/tratar esse arquivo.

No entanto é possível utilizar apenas JavaScript para cuidar do upload, utilizando o [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/). Caso você queira, também pode usar outras tecnologias, como [Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) e seus [milhares de frameworks web](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks), [Ruby](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info) com o [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) ou qualquer outra linguagem que funcione no back-end.

Answer (score 4):

Não. Uma aplicação no lado do servidor tem que receber o arquivo e fazer alguma coisa com o arquivo – por exemplo, salvá-lo no sistema de arquivos.

Agora, se você quiser uma aplicação *apenas javascript*, é possível fazê-lo usando jQuery para o lado do cliente e uma tecnologia javascript para o lado do servidor, como por exemplo [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).